# The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.3, but with current settings, version 2.1.3-servicing-26724-03 would be used instead

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Got this error today after upgrading VS2017 to v15.8.2 and trying to build my dotnet core project (target framework .NET Core 2.1):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     NETSDK1061: The project was restored using
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.3, but with current settings,
>   version 2.1.3-servicing-26724-03 would be used instead. To resolve
>   this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for
>   subsequent operations such as build or publish. Typically this issue
>   can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or
>   publish but not during restore. For more information, see
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-runtime-patch-selection.

What to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found out solution:

Uninstall .NET Core SDK 2.1.401, that came with vs2017 v15.8.2 and install it again using an installer from the [.NET Downloads page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).

Source: @joshuadavidson [https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9897](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9897#issuecomment-416942858)

Also quote @peterhuene:

> "It's come to my attention that VS 15.8.2 did not include the correct,
>   final build of the 2.1.401 SDK. We are working on resolving this
>   issue. In the meantime, uninstalling the 2.1.401 SDK installed by
>   Visual Studio and installing the SDK from the .NET Downloads site
>   should correct the issue."

**Update, September 7th 2018:**

- or simply upgrade to VS2017 v15.8.3, where [the problem is resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.3):

> "Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.2 contained a pre-release build of
>   .NET Core SDK 2.1.401 that is incompatible with Visual Studio. We have
>   corrected this issue with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.3."

Comment: I only installed the new sdk without uninstalling the existing , and it worked for me , thanks

Comment: if this don´t help you (as in my case) check this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518059/how-to-resolve-net-core-build-error-netdsdk1061-and-warning-msb3277/