# Why is ArtifactoryNuget@1 pipeline task restoring against old Microsoft.NetCore.App version?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, artifactory

I'm using ArtifactoryNuget@1 task to restore NugetPackages from JFrog Artifactory. My Azure DevOps pipeline started to suddenly fail a week ago (31.1.2020) due the artifactory task restoring using Microsoft.NetCore.App version 2.1.14 where the DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks after it use the version 2.1.15.

The actual error I'm getting from the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task is: `NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.14, but with current settings, version 2.1.15 would be used instead. To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish. Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not during restore.`

I'm doing self-contained deployment for the .Net Core deployment project so the project file has been set up for that.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

Pipeline is configured like this:

```
- task: ArtifactoryNuGet@1
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    artifactoryService: 'xxxx'
    solutionPath: 'xxxx.sln'
    targetResolveRepo: nuget

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: xxxx.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --runtime win10-x64 --no-restore
```

Everything worked beautifully before but now I cannot get the solution to build properly in Azure DevOps (local build works). My best guess is that the DevOps pipeline machines were updated with the 2.1.15 runtime but the JFrog ArtifactoryNuget task cannot utilize for some reason and it ends up using 2.1.14.

I've tried to see from the [task source code](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-vsts-extension/tree/master/tasks/ArtifactoryNuget) how the version is selected but I think that goes into Nuget internals. I've also tried setting it explicitly with `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` but that caused the ArtifactoryNuGet@1 task to use even older version 2.1.1. The nuget repo itself is a virtual repo combining nuget.local and nuget.remote.

The questions:

- Why has this broken suddenly? Is it because of version updates in the Azure pipeline machines or something else?
- Why does the ArtifactoryNuGet@1 get the version 2.1.14 if the other tasks use 2.1.15 when using the "TargetLatestRuntimePatch"?
- Is there a way to specify the runtime identifier (e.g. win10-x64) to the ArtifactoryNuGet@1 task as is suggested by the error message?

Thanks!

NOTE: The marked answer is a non-optimal workaround for the issue until something actually fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it will request the latest patch installed when set `TargetLatestRuntimePatch` to `true` in the project file.

So, please make sure the version `Microsoft.NetCore.App version 2.1.15` is existing in the Artifactory. According to your description seems the latest patch is `version 2.1.14` in your JFrog Artifactory service.

If you scenario, please try this :

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
   <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
   <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.14</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.1.14" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If that doesn't work, please reference below links for further troubleshoot:

- [How to resolve .net core build error NETDSDK1061 and warning MSB3277](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518059/how-to-resolve-net-core-build-error-netdsdk1061-and-warning-msb3277/)
- [Self-contained deployment runtime roll forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the JFrog artifactory and the latest patch wound was `Microsoft.NETCore.App.2.1.15.nupkg`. In case of these framework-level packages, is the runtime roll forward done in the client or in the Nuget repo? I understood from the documentation that it checks the runtimes installed in the client machine to choose which ones to use? Also. I think you are not supposed to give version number for the "Microsoft.NetCore.App"? I'll try with the suggested config.

Comment: OK, tried this and got rid of the error. Actually noticed now that there was similiar one regarding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` but that couldn't be removed with the similar `<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.14" />` line. Still thinking if specifying the patch version is a good idea because that would make opting in to security releases a matter of changing the versions (in 24 project files in this case) explicitly.

Comment: Also as a side note, I tried using DotNetCoreCLI@2 restore instead of ArtifactoryNuGet@1 restore and it handled the 2.1.15 normally. The problem is that I need some libraries from the JFrog artifactory which either prevents this option or requires me to include the required libraries locally in my repo.

Comment: This sounds like an issue for `ArtifactoryNuGet@1` task, The `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task has the expected behavior, since the task 
 `ArtifactoryNuGet@1` is a third-party extension task, recommend that you could submit a question in the extension Q&A area : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension&ssr=false#qna

Comment: Posted the question there as well. I'll mark your answer for now because this is what I ended up using for now. This solution leads gives out `NETSDK1071: A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' specified a Version of `2.1.14`. Specifying the version of this package is not recommended.` which reflects what MS documentation says about [non-implicit versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#implicit-package-references).